# Error when start android app on Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, maps

I'm trying to show a map on my android app in Xamarin, but I had a problem when I try to see the map:

```
12-11 11:11:33.122 E/Google Maps Android API( 1254): Authorization failure.  
Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
12-11 11:11:33.126 E/Google Maps Android API( 1254): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
12-11 11:11:33.126 E/Google Maps Android API( 1254): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
12-11 11:11:33.126 E/Google Maps Android API( 1254): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
12-11 11:11:33.126 E/Google Maps Android API( 1254): API Key: .....
12-11 11:11:33.126 E/Google Maps Android API( 1254): Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): .....;.....
```

I check that the API IS enabled, but I don't know what the problem can be.

Comment: [Have you seen this document?](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/)

Comment: Yeah, I have read it a lot of times, but It doesn't help.

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Comment: Done... I upload the error message, thank you